# In JSP,I entered a float value into a session variable.How could I access it and convert back into float?

Tags: jsp

In a JSP, I entered a float value into a session variable. How can I access it and convert back into float?

```
float time=10.00;
session.setAttribute("ntime",time);
```

Comment: you have not yet accepted any answer

Answer (score 2):

Duh. With [`session.getAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29):

```
float f = (Float) session.getAttribute("ntime");
```

Answer (score 2):

For setting:

```
session.setAttribute("number", new Float(10.0));
```

For getting:

```
Float f = (Float) session.getAttribute("number");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Float time = (Float) session.getAttribute("ntime");
```

The session attribute will be of type `Float` (the object) rather than `float` (the primitive). The cast is required because `getAttribute` returns type `Object`.

Make sure to check that `time` isn't null before you try and use it. Sooner or later, someone will invoke your JSP with a clean session, and that value will be null. If you directly cast to `float` rather than `Float`, you run the risk of hard-to-debug null-pointer exceptions. Once you've done the null-check, then cast `time` to `float`